# set attributes in the scaffold generation statement for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When you create a model in Rails, you do so by something like this:

$ `rails g scaffold ModelName attributeName1:type attributeName2:type attributeName3:type` ...

Is there a way to declare the default values from the generations statement, or do you have to do that in the migration file BEFORE migrating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter; Setting default column values **at the database level** is done by manually modifying the migration files before running them.